# How can I count a word from all lines that are 2 rows after a specific line?

Tags: python

So, this might sound a bit confusing, I'll try to explain it. For example from these lines:

```
next line 1
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
red blue dark ten lemon
next line 2
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
hat 45 no dad fate orange
next line 3
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tan rat lovely lemon eat 
you him lemon Daniel her"
```

I am only interested in the count of "lemon" from lines that have "next line" two lines above it. So, the output I expect is "2 lemons".

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

My attempt so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#import the numpy library
 import numpy as np

  lemon = 0

  logfile = open('file','r')

  for line in logfile:

  words = line.split()

  words = np.array(words)
  if np.any(words == 'next line'):
    if np.any(words == 'lemon'):
        lemon +=1
print "Total number of lemons is %d" % (lemon)
```

but this counts "lemon" only if it's on the same line as "next line".

Comment: In your example the search criterion does not match at all. 'next' is never followed by 'lemon' two lines below.

Comment: Yes, it is. Line 1 - next line 1, Line 2 - ^^^^^^^^, Line 3 - red blue dark ten lemon etc

Comment: ah, ok. You posted the text with additional newlines between every line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each line you need to be able to access to two line before it. For that aim you can use `itertools.tee` in order to create two independent file object (which are iterator-like objects) then use `itertools.izip()` in order to create your your expected pairs:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
with open('file') as logfile:
    spam, logfile = tee(logfile)
    # consume first two line of spam
    next(spam)
    next(spam)
    for pre, line in izip(logfile, spam):
        if 'next line' in pre:
             print line.count('lemon')
```

Or if you just want to count the lines you can use a generator expression within `sum()`:

```
from itertools import tee, izip
with open('file') as logfile:
    spam, logfile = tee(logfile)
    # consume first two lines of spam
    next(spam)
    next(spam)
    print sum(line.count('lemon') for pre, line in izip(logfile, spam) if 'next line' in pre)
```

Comment: Hi Kasramvd, If I need to do the opposite (count two lines above of a certain line, instead of below), do I just exchange 'next line' and 'lemon' in your code?

Comment: @EmilyT. Count two lines above a certain line, based on what kind of condition? if there is no condition just count the liens and multiply by 2.

Comment: So basically, when you see 'next line', count the word lemon in the line that's two rows above.

Comment: @EmilyT. You want to count the word `lemon` or the lines that have that word? is this what you wanted from the original question too?

Comment: I want to count the word lemon and yeah, but I didn't specify it in the original I now realize

Comment: @EmilyT. So in this case you can change `line.count('lemon')` to `pre.count('lemon')` and  `if 'next line' in pre)` to `if 'next line' in line)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! One more thing, when I do the summation, it gives me the following error: " print sum(pre.count('lemon') in line for pre, line in izip(logfile, spam) if 'next line' in line)
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int". I'm not sure I understand why. Any suggestions?

Comment: @EmilyT. There was a typo in that line :-), check out the update!

Comment: It works now, thank you! It doesn't count the very last one for some reason but I can just add 1.

Comment: one more question (sorry. last one) I tried to do the count for two words by just adding another print line   :  print sum(line.count('lovely')for pre, line in izip(logfile, spam) if 'next line' in pre) but it doesn't count anything but the first word. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @EmilyT. What you mean by the *first word*? are you considering the case-sensitivity of the `str.count()` function?

Comment: @EmilyT. If this answer worked for you, you can tell this to community by accepting it!

Comment: I don't think I am. I did this - print sum(line.count('lemon')for pre, line in izip(logfile, spam) if 'next line' in pre)+1
   print sum(line.count('lovely')for pre, line in izip(logfile, spam) if 'next line' in pre)+1. So basically, the same line, different word for counting

Comment: @EmilyT. There is no different between them, please survey your code and your file accurately and see what the problem. Exactly, if you had another problem that you couldn't find it by searching you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over the file (which is an iterator) and call `next` two times whenever you find a `next line` line, then `count` how often `lemon` appears, with both the `for` loop and the calls to `next` are using the same iterator.

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    lemon_count = 0
    for line in f:
        if "next line" in line:
            next(f) # skip next line
            lemon_count += next(f).count("lemon") # get count for next-next line
```

For your example, `lemon_count` ends up as `2`. That is assuming that there is no other `next` line in between a `next` line and the `lemon` line, or that the `lemon` line itself is a `next` line.

Comment: Hi tobias, Can I do the same for 2 lines above instead of below?

Comment: @EmilyT. Two above is more difficult, because you can't go backwards in an iterator. You could use my approach and just reverse the conditions, i.e. check if `lemon` is in the line, advance two lines, then check whether that's a "next line" line, but this might miss lemons if there are lemons both three and two lines above  a "next line". In this case @Kasramvd approach would work better.